# Why is List<T>.Exists slower than a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, loops, generic-list

I'm in WinForms and before saving changes to the DataBase, I had to check whether the used ErrorProvider holds an error for any of the displayed Controls.

I figured out several ways to do that among them:

- a simple foreach loop over the ControlContainer:

  ```
      foreach (Control c in ctrlcontainer)
      {
          if (epOrderHeader.GetError(c) != string.Empty)
          {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  ```
- Using the List extension Method Exists(Predicate):

  return (ctrlcontainer.Exists(c => epOrderHeader.GetError(c) != string.Empty);

Right from the stomache I expected the second to be the fastest, but using the Eqatec Profiler I discovered, that the foreach loop is slightly faster (in my case about 1ms). While this is insignificant, I still wonder why this happens?

How does the compiler translate these methods and why is the first one faster?

Comment: 1ms of how many ms? how often did you perform the loop?

Comment: How many runs have you done? To compare the speed of the different approaches? 1ms is insignificant, and unless you've done 1000 runs and the 1ms is an average, it could be the OS slowing it slightly down, and have nothing to do you code.

Comment: Could the timing of a delegate invocation have anything to do with it? On the other hand, if one offered me a trade of `1ms` in exchange for shaving off an entire loop, I'd take it in a heartbeat :):):)

Comment: @Botz3000: I tried it again, starting each Method 10.000 times. The difference is minimal, about ~10 ms for 10.000 runs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably 1 ms slower in your case because `List<T>.Exists` calls `FindIndex` which is implemented in the following way:

```
public int FindIndex(int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (startIndex > this._size)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.startIndex, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }
    if (count < 0 || startIndex > this._size - count)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.count, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Count);
    }
    if (match == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    int num = startIndex + count;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (match(this._items[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So this is a little bit more than a simple [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3207y01.aspx).

Comment: the execution pointer has passed through two overloads of `Exists` before even getting to `FindIndex`, adding to the "load". Generally these methods exist not for performance reasons, but to aid the clarity of the code, allowing for a more "declarative" style of development.

Comment: So the answer to my question is: .Exists() and a foreach loop are two completely different things (as .Exists() essentially tries to find the Index of the first item matching the predicate) and are therefore not comparable like e.g .Foreach() and foreach?

Comment: @buddybubble: They are two different things. Comparable but not equal. The index part doesn't cost much just as the two overloads or the additional validation checks in `FindIndex`. But in total it is enough for your 1 millisecond. Btw, `ForEach` and `foreach` are also slightly different(i would assume that the `ForEach` method is little bit more efficient). But that is an other question :)

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: Ok thank you I'm marking your comment as the answer. And I just re-read my comment. I meant .Foreach() and foreach do NOT work the same way, but the way is said that is misleading ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect the List.Exists method to be faster?
In essence it does the same as your manual check, but one thing it does do extra, is the check using a Predicate instead of a direct check. This must cost a little performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the function `SetError` in the Controls inside `ctrlcontainer` then you could track when an error has occurred. I would suggest either extending the class `ErrorProvider` with your customized class or including that provider inside one of your classes so you can override the `SetError` method i.e. you don't need to check anything and therefore the comparison between `Exists` and `foreach` is not relevant.

Comment: I agree with you, and would consider this to be a better style.
But just to get your suggestions right: You are talking about an extension Method vs. a customized (derived) ErrorProvider?

But I still find the Exists vs foreach comparison intersting, as this is something not only limited to this particular example, but rather something I'd like to understand in general ;)